# Conditional functions in excel (IF AND)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a conditional formula given:

B1= 1 if American, 0 if European

B2= 1 if call, 0 if put

How can I nest a function so that the cell will produce "x" if B1= 1 AND B2=1, but will produce "y" if B1=1 AND B2=0

Basically, I need B1 to be equal to 1 in both situations, but B2 can be either 1 or 0 and there will be different outcomes for each situation.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(B1=1,IF(B2=1,"x","y"),"B1 does not equal 1")
```